# Let $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function so that $f(x)f'(x) < 0$.Which of following is true?

Tags: functions

Let $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function so that $f(x)f'(x) <  0$.Which of following is true?

$f$ is increasing function

$f$ is decreasing function

$|f|$ is increasing function

$|f|$ is decreasing function

**ATTEMPT**

If I take $f(x)=e^{-x}$, then i am left with option B and D. How to choose from them? Thanks

Comment: $(f(x)^2)'<0$ so $|f(x)|$ is decreasing.

Comment: Look at Kay K's komment.

Comment: @kccu it is increasing function.isn't it?

Comment: To see that $f$ need not be decreasing look at $f(x)=-e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you're a student. Thus I will give general suggestions. First try to think of counterexamples to each of the 4 statements. Ex: For the first try to think of a differentiable $f$ such that $f(x)f'(x)<0$ and yet $f$ is not increasing. If that doesn't work then try and construct a proof that the statement is true. An intuitive meaning of $f(x)f'(x) < 0$ is that both the function and its derivative are never zero and also if $f(x)$ is positive then $f'(x)$ is negative and if $f(x)$ is negative then $f'(x)$ is positive. It may be helpful for your intuition if you remember that the differentiability of $f$ implies its continuity. I would guess that you're either in first or second semester calculus or perhaps an elementary analysis class.

Comment: The first statement is not true. Let $f = -x + 1$ for $x \in (-\infty, 1)$ and $f = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \in [1,\infty)$. I suppose this is all I will give.